Request help marrying two VBA scripts together (Find/Replace)
Attempting to add Find/Replace to existing code
Starting with this piece of code which works to convert a .CSV to an .XLS File:
Sub CSVtoXLS()
'UpdatebyExtendoffice20170814
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xSPath As String
    Dim xCSVFile As String
    Dim xWsheet As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.StatusBar = True
    xWsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFd.Title = "Select a folder:"
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xSPath = xFd.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Right(xSPath, 1) <> "\" Then xSPath = xSPath + "\"
    xCSVFile = Dir(xSPath & "*.csv")
    Do While xCSVFile <> ""
        Application.StatusBar = "Converting: " & xCSVFile
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=xSPath & xCSVFile
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(xSPath & xCSVFile, ".csv", ".xlsx", vbTextCompare), xlWorkbookDefault
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Windows(xWsheet).Activate
        xCSVFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Added:
Sub Find_Replace1()
Range("A2:A100000").Replace What:="C:\", Replacement:="Z:\"
End Sub

but it does not work. Can't even save the module
I want to perform the Find/Replace while the file is open.
They both work stand alone.
Sub CSVtoXLS()
'UpdatebyExtendoffice20170814
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xSPath As String
    Dim xCSVFile As String
    Dim xWsheet As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.StatusBar = True
    xWsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFd.Title = "Select a folder:"
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xSPath = xFd.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Right(xSPath, 1) <> "\" Then xSPath = xSPath + "\"
    xCSVFile = Dir(xSPath & "*.csv")
    Do While xCSVFile <> ""
        Application.StatusBar = "Converting: " & xCSVFile
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=xSPath & xCSVFile

        **Sub Find_Replace1()
        Range("A2:A100000").Replace What:="C:\", Replacement:="Z:\"
        End Sub**

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(xSPath & xCSVFile, ".csv", ".xlsx", vbTextCompare), xlWorkbookDefault
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Windows(xWsheet).Activate
        xCSVFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

I have incorporated the solution per jdweng.
Here is my final working code in case someone can use it...
Sub CSVtoXLS()
'UpdatebyExtendoffice20170814
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xSPath As String
    Dim xCSVFile As String
    Dim xWsheet As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.StatusBar = True
    xWsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFd.Title = "Select a folder:"
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xSPath = xFd.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Right(xSPath, 1) <> "\" Then xSPath = xSPath + "\"
    xCSVFile = Dir(xSPath & "*.csv")
    Do While xCSVFile <> ""
        Application.StatusBar = "Converting: " & xCSVFile
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=xSPath & xCSVFile
        Worksheets(1).Range("A2:A100000").Replace What:="C:\", Replacement:="Z:\" 
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(xSPath & xCSVFile, ".csv", ".xlsx", vbTextCompare), xlWorkbookDefault
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Windows(xWsheet).Activate
        xCSVFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub


Try : Worksheets(1).Range("A2:A100000").Replace What:="C:", Replacement:="Z:"

YOU! Are my hero! Thank you!
I don't see how to mark this as answered or credit you.
